# How do I get the following limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having a blackout...

How do I solve 
$$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}?$$

Comment: L'Hospital's rule should work just fine here.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski No it doesn't. You get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}$$

Comment: Your right. I goofed.

Comment: L Hospital, after the substitution $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: Question: is it possible to make the argument that $\exp$ converges faster than any power of $x$, therefore the numerator goes to $0$ faster, and the limit is $0$? Or is it complete nonsense?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski No you didn't. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

$$\left|{e^{-{1 \over x^2}} \over x} \right|= {1 \over |x|} {1 \over e^{{1 \over x^2}} } \le {1 \over |x|} {1 \over {1+{1 \over x^2}}}= {1 \over {|x|+{1 \over |x|}}} = { |x| \over 1+ x^2}$$

Comment: Please forgive my edit, but I was squinting.

Comment: @Arkamis: Thanks for relieving my eye strain...

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = \lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty} xe^{-x^2}$$

After making the substitution $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ and depending on $x \to 0^{\pm}$. Either way the limit is $0$.

Comment: Argh, thats easy... :-) I just tried L'Hospital without the substitution. Thanks!

Comment: @siwica L'Hospital works fine too but I was going to suggest squeeze theorem. Look at copper.hat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to get to the same answer:

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \ln\left(\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}\right) = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\ln(x)=-\infty \implies \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=e^{-\infty}=0$

Answer (score 1):

L'Hôpital actually works if you use the $\frac\infty\infty$ version:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x^{-2}}}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{-1}}{e^{x^{-2}}}\overset{\text{L'H}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x^{-2}}{-2x^{-3}e^{x^{-2}}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{2e^{x^{-2}}}=\frac0\infty=0$$

Comment: (and nitpickers use the one sided version of L'Hôpital twice)

Comment: Nicely done, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}$$
Let $h=\frac{1}{x}$, then
$$ \lim\limits_{h\to \pm\infty} h\exp\left(-h^2\right)= \lim\limits_{h\to \pm\infty} \frac{h}{\exp\left(h^2\right)} $$
$$
= \lim\limits_{h\to \pm\infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dh}h}{\frac{d}{dh}\exp\left(h^2\right)} = \lim\limits_{h\to \pm\infty} \frac{1}{2h\exp\left(h^2\right)}=0
$$

Comment: yes, sciona already suggested this...

Comment: @siwica, I'm well aware of sciona's suggestion. I added the steps to further assist the you...

Comment: ok, thank you! But the rest ist trivial once you get the initial idea.

Comment: @siwica, this question in its entirety is trivial...